# Xdebug is always resetting session with phpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Ether my status never came cross before or I don't know how to google it! my development environment got updated to ubuntu 14.04, phpStorm 2016.1 (still in trial version), java version "1.7.0_95".
all settings are fine and I can debug, but after debugging start (a bout a minute or less), all debugging session gets terminates OR restarts from the first break point.
also I get a lot of "Debug Session was finished without being paused" notice without making any debug request (see attached plz).

[image]

please let me know what to check or what could be the reason.
Thanks in advance.

---

### **Update** :

### following is xdebug settings in php.ini

```
[xdebug] 
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

---

development framework is magento 1.14.2 EE

Comment: from the menu, 'Run' > break at first line in php scripts <--- untick this

Comment: Thank you, this unticked, I meant by first break point is the first break point I added not first line in my code :)

Comment: It may help if you post your php.ini config for xdebug, and also a general outline of the code.  I get the "Debug session finished without being paused" note a lot when I have the pause points set on lines of code that aren't executed when I load a particular page.

Comment: @Thornview please check the update. and regarding the notification, I'm getting it without even trying to start a debugging session.

Comment: Have you try play wit hte path mapping ? 
CTRL + ALT + S (Settings) 
Language & Framework > PHP > Servers - this sometimes help me 
Also xDebug have troubles for break on array creation if no single line so place the breake point on line "$a = [" dont take any effect but on "];" will stop :)

Answer (score 3):

You have the `remote_autostart` turned on, so every time you reload the page xDebug tries to debug the script, even if you weren't meaning to.

According to [the documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)

> When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will always attempt to start a
>   remote debugging session and try to connect to a client, even if the
>   GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not present.

Set `xdebug.remote_autostart = 0` and that should stop the errant messages about debugging.

Comment: thank you, at least one issue got solved :), still xdebug session is getting terminated ..

Comment: That will be trickier to resolve without seeing the code and walking through the debugging session.  I can't think of what would cause a reset like that.

Comment: Thank you .. I know it's trickier but not possible to paste all code here ( code is normal magento code) and it's happening every where (session termination), so I don't think it's related to executed code it self. should be some component that usually affects Xdebug (like OS, php_fpm, nginx ... etc)

Comment: I'm experiencing this too and I'm stuck. PHP is a PITA. I don't experience this with Python nor Go.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me alot with your answer. Also deleted remote xdebug log file, the path is configured in php.init as `xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

Go to PHPStorm - Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug

... Section "External connections" -> "Break at first line in PHP scripts" ... disable this option

Additional suggestion:

... Section "Xdebug" -> disable the last two checkboxes ("Force break at first line...")

... Section "Advanced settings" -> disable "Notify if debug session was finished without being paused"

Comment: Thanks, you helped me alot with your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll quote a clear response [from the official forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206315469-Debug-session-was-finished-without-being-paused?page=1#community_comment_206814275)

> You are right it's fine to have debug session without any breakpoints reached, e.g. it's common if you have Ajax request. 
>   The warning is intend to help new users to configure debugger. If "Break at first line" option is disabled and there's some error that silently prevent you to setup breakpoints (e.g. there's a typo in path mappings at PHP|Servers, remote and local file versions are not synchronized, etc) then nothing will happen on page reload. This situation is indistinguishable from xdebug misconfiguration (e.g. wrong "xdebug.remote_host", "xdebug.remote_port") therefore you may spend a lot of time to figure out the problem. The message is saying that debugger itself is configured correctly and suggest you next step in troubleshooting process.
>
> If you have no problem and debug session without breakpoints is expected behavior then just disable it

Comment: I'm having this same problem on windows. The problem is _not_ exiting due to not hitting any breakpoints. The problem _is:_ you have reached a breakpoint and have stepped through some code, then you wait a little while reviewing variables/expressions etc, and the debug pane in Phpstorm just goes blank, all variables/values disappear, you can no longer use the stepping buttons and the server returns a 500 response to the client.

Comment: thank you for your response, for me it was fixed after updating both php => php 7 & Xdebug to latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you use php_fpm, so try running

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: already tried to restart all my environment services, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> but after debugging start (a bout a minute or less), all debugging session gets terminates OR restarts from the first break point

I finally found a solution to this. My Apache configuration was set to terminate idle connections after 40 seconds - stopping the debug session and returning a 500 error to the client.

To fix this open your apache httpd.conf file and look for the following setting

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

If you are using this module, set or change the value of the following directive

```
FcgidIOTimeout 300
```

This setting defaults to 40 seconds if it is not specified, setting it to 300 will allow 5 minutes per connection before apache terminates it.

Answer (score 0):

most of other answers are valid, but in my case it was incompatibility between PHP version and Xdebug version.
so the solution for me was updating both PHP => PHP 7 & Xdebug to latest stable version.
I felt like it's better to mention it in a separate answer in case anybody might come into same case.

**update**: xdebug 3.1.2 working settings:

config file path: /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini
settings:

> zend_extension=xdebug.so
> xdebug.mode=debug
> xdebug.start_with_request=yes
> xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
> xdebug.client_port=9003
> xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
> xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
> xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
> xdebug.idekey = "x_debug"